# What are the best approaches to follow when you create lightning components for managed pakage?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, managed-package, namespace

We created **lightning components** -without namespaces- and tested them successfully.  At the time of packaging, (when a namespace is added) we had to prefix `nameSpace__` before every field name, object name, labels and other components in each and every component and that lead to lot of bugs.

Basically we ended up replacing all

- `Label.c.` with `label.namespace`.
- `c:componentName` with `namespace:componentName`
- prefix `namespace__` before every fields and objects ending with `__c' and '__r`.

We wasted almost 2 weeks for the whole process. Now our app is ready and is under review.

We are about to start the 2nd phase of product with a different namespace (say 'namespace2'). How should we approach this? Should we have to 'replace all' `namespace` with `namespace2`? Or as [this](https://www.codescience.com/blog/2016/making-your-lightning-component-namespace-safe) blog suggests, should we never hard code namespace in lightning components?

Or we should hard code namespaces as per the Salesforce [developer guide](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/namespace_using_reference.htm?search_text=namespace).

Which approach is adopted at your org?

Comment: The correct solution is to use DX. This allows you to develop using your namespace so you don't spend time doing this.

Comment: Thank you @sfdcfox, I am new to packaging related stuffs . About Salesforce DX, I have seen some YouTube videos and seems interesting. l will definitely try to make use of DX going forward.

Answer (score 3):

While @sfdcfox gave you the right answer in comments (use DX), smart use of message classes can solve a lot of problems in this scenario.

Instead of using direct objects, or labels embedded in the component, create a class that encapsulate these things and leverage the fact that Apex does handle namespaces correctly.

For example

*Message Class*

```
public class MyMessages {
  public class MyMessage {
    @AuraEnabled
    public Map<String, String> labels {get;set;}
    @AuraEnabled
    public MyWrapper myObj {get;set;}
  }

  public class MyWrapper {
    @AuraEnabled
    public String myProp1 {get;set;}
    @AuraEnabled
    public String myProp2 {get;set;}

    void MyWrapper(MyObject__c obj) {
      myProp1 = obj.myProp1__c;
      myProp2 = obj.myProp2__c;
    }
  }
}
```

*Class*

```
@AuraEnabled
public static MyMessages.MyMessage getPageInfo(Id recID) {
  msgClass = new MyMessages.MyMessage();

  msgClass.labels.put('label1',System.Label.Label1);  
  msgClass.labels.put('label2',System.Label.Label2);

  MyObject__c obj = [select Id, myProp1__c, myProp2__c from MyObject__c where id = :recId]; 
  msgClass.myObj = new MyMessages.MyWrapper(obj);

  return msgClass;
}
```

**Component**

```
<aura:attribute access="public" name="myObj" type="Object" />

{!myObj.labels.label1} <br/>
{!myObj.labels.label2} <br/>
{!myObj.myObj.myProp1} <br/>
{!myObj.myObj.myProp2} <br/>
```

**Helper**

In the helper call the remote method and then

```
component.set("v.myObj", <variable with Object);
```

Comment: Thank you @sebastian-kessel. Your code is an awesome hack..! But, for now, I have decided to give Salesforce DX a try. I will try this if my team is not willing to go with DX. Thank you again.

Comment: That's the best idea anyway. Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

+1 for Sebastian and sfdcfox

As for Labels - in most - not all cases those get handled correctly by the packaging engine. There is nothing to do if they are e.g. referenced in the component body like so:

`<!-- my cmp body -->
{!$Label.c.myCustomLabel}`

Also `instanceOf c:myCustomComponent` will work like a charm after packaging without further editing.

Getting a label in the JS Controller though `$A.getReference('$Label.c.myLabel')` does not (always?) seem to work. Which means those labels must be added to the package by using some workaround (e.g.referencing them invisibly in VF or elsewhere).

Please note that `JSON.serialize` or just returning an `sObject` to the Lightning Controller will append the Namespace to each fieldname. We strip or append this namespace if need be.

Ultimately we hope namespace support will get better in time and for the actual swapping of namespace issue, there's DX for that.

Comment: Thank you @christian-szandor-knapp , we have included all those 'stubborn' labels, ( which were not willing to be a part of package) in a separate VF page and added that in the package.