# Are custom labels referenced only in Lightning Components automatically packaged?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, managed-package, package, customlabel, unmanaged-package

This (not marked as delivered) idea [Custom Label Auto Packaging in Lightning Components](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=0873A000000CLYSQA4) has a "Latest Comment from Salesforce" of:

> Farhan Tahir - 5 months ago
>
> This is coming in Spring'18!!

The very ugly workaround seems to be to reference the labels in e.g. an Apex class so they are automatically packaged.

Are custom labels referenced only in Lightning Components automatically packaged?

**PS**

Also see Manjot's comment. There are 2 cases: the .cmp files files:

```
{!$Label.c.labelName}
```

and the .js files:

```
$A.get("$Label.namespace.labelName")
```

Also see this July 2017 post [Packaging custom labels used in ligthning helpers and controllers](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/185617/packaging-custom-labels-used-in-ligthning-helpers-and-controllers).

Comment: labels in .cmp file were auto packaged but not in js files. But that was working even before winter 18. I do not know whether labels in js file are auto added in package after winter 18.

Comment: I don't believe current implementations auto-package them in all cases but I _can_ confirm the workaround solution of referencing them in an apex class (usually the LC controller or a constants class) with a comment like "don't touch these references". :-)

Comment: I concur: Labels referenced in js controller only still need to be put into Apex or VF

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say it's partially working after performing some tests. I've created a Salesforce ticket in order to report and address this bug. Anyway I'd like to share my findings.

Let's consider 3 scenarios:

**Scenario 1 (working)** - The label already exists and then you save the component controller/helper on the package org. So when packaging it should include the labels and tag them as *managed*.

**Scenario 2 (not working)** - The label doesn't exist yet and then you save a component controller/helper on the package org. Later you create the label.

**Scenario 3 (not working)** - When deploying an unmanaged package to the package org with component bundles and labels.

The behavior of $Label getting included in packages when referenced inside components, controllers or helpers is called as **resource spidering** (I received this information from Salesforce).
Seems that it's triggering the resource spidering only when following the step 1.

Hope this helps.

Find below some code used to test this issue.

*Component*:

```
<aura:component>
    <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.onInit}" />
    <lightning:button aura:id="new" label="{!$Label.hook.Label1}" onclick="{!c.onNewClick}"/>
</aura:component>
```

*ComponentController.js*:

```
({
    onInit : function(component, event, helper) {
        console.log($A.get("$Label.hook.Label2"));
    },
    onNewClick : function(component, event, helper) {
        helper.onNewClick(component, event);
        console.log($A.get("$Label.hook.Label3"));
    }
})
```

*ComponentHelper.js*:

```
({
    onNewClick : function() {
        console.log($A.get("$Label.hook.Label4"));
    }
})
```